# Quiz application - How can I choose 3 wrong answers to show from an array of 6 wrong answers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a quiz app and I am new to IOS.I want to get 3 wrong answers from an array  of 6 wrong answers for a specific question and there will be 1 correct answer for each question.I want to randomize the wrong options every time the question is shown.So every time the question is shown the app will choose 3 wrong options from the array and 1 correct answer.How can I code this?I would be glad if you can help me on this.

Thank you..

```
{
    int counted = [theOptions count];

    int i;



    NSMutableArray *indexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:counted];

    for (i=0; i<counted; i++) [indexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    NSMutableArray *shuffle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:counted];
    while ([indexes count])
    {
        int index = rand()%[indexes count];
        [shuffle addObject:[indexes objectAtIndex:index]];
        [indexes removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }

    NSMutableArray* shuffledOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    for (int i=0; i<counted; i++)
    {
        int randomIndex = [[shuffle objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        [shuffledOptions addObject:[theOptions objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
        UIButton* optionButton = [_optionsButtonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        optionButton.tag = randomIndex;

    }
    return shuffledOptions;

}

return theOptions;}
```

Comment: What have you attempted to do thus far? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: StackOverflow can only help you with specific problems with your code.  It's not a site for people to write applications for you.  If you can start writing your app and come back to StackOverflow with specific questions then we can help.

Comment: Post what you've attempted and I'm sure many will be happy to help.

Comment: by the way I was using this code to randomize the index positions.But I was still thinking of a way to randomize the answers.Thanks to the friend below for the solution.I updated some code and it is working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of 6 wrong answers and want to randomly select three of them

```
NSArray *answers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Wrong #1", @"Wrong #2", @"Wrong #3", @"Wrong #4", @"Wrong #5", @"Wrong #6"];
NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int r;
while (output.count < 3) {
r = arc4random_uniform(5);
if (![output containsObject:[answers objectAtIndex:r]]) {
[output addObject:[answers objectAtIndex:r]];
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be select a random number between 0-5 then select another random one. If the next one is a duplicate of the first one repeat the previous step. Do this one more time and you now have three unique random numbers from 0-5.

A more clever way would be to store numbers 1-5 in an array. Shuffle the array and then return the first three indexes.

Good luck.